# Visual Studio Pro 2012 crashes with a MissingFieldException immediately after opening a solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have downloaded some source code from our TFS and my setup is via VPN. I installed the same VS2012 installer in my machine at home and my machine at the office.

As soon as I open the solution Visual Studio 2012 crashes. I tried uninstalling, running CCleaner, then re-installing but I am still having errors.

The following facts are relevant:

- I have admin rights to this PC
- It does have other versions of Visual Studio installed
- I have the latest Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012 patches

The following is from the crash report:

> Problem signature: Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
>        Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
>        Problem Signature 02: 11.0.50727.1 
>        Problem Signature 03: 5011ecaa 
>        Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.LanguageService.CSharp
>        Problem Signature 05: 11.0.50727.1
>        Problem Signature 06: 5011cc19
>        Problem Signature 07: 131
>        Problem Signature 08: 43
>        Problem Signature 09: System.MissingFieldException
>        OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>        Locale ID: 1033 
>        Additional Information 1: 0a9e
>        Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>        Additional Information 3: 0a9e
>        Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>        Read our privacy statement online: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409 If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline: C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: That version number doesn't look healthy, current version is 11.0.51106.1.  I'm guessing you had a beta version of VS installed on that machine and it didn't get properly uninstalled.  Google "vs2012 beta cleanup" to find hits.

Answer (score 7):

**The solution for me was to download and apply the [first update](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-additional-software) from the official download page.**

I've had the exact same problem with VS 2012 Ultimate.

The problem seems to be that at least the ISO-download of the 3 official downloads comes with the same, outdated version as yours, and I got the exact same exception every time I opened a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hey renamed the "ComponentModelCache" folder in %localappdata%\microsoft\visualstudio\11.0\

This resolved the issue.